# Best search option for a heroku-hosted Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, heroku

I've been working on a new project lately where a fantastic search engine is crucial. It's a rails3 app hosted on heroku and I'm looking into possible solutions(a rubygem would be ideal) which offer a easy way to have powerful full-text search.

Right now, I'm using acts_as_tsearch which leverages PostgreSQL and performs a basic MATCH query. Though, it's not really pulling back good results(for example, if I search for "create a project" and "how do i create a project" exists as a query, it doesn't find it).

Can anyone share their experiences with full text search, anyone tried out Solr ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[IndexTank](http://www.indextank.com) is your best bet. They were recently added as a [Heroku add-on](http://docs.heroku.com/indextank).

We recently tried to just run our own search for our Heroku app and it's just not worth it because you have to worry about stability and scaling of that search box.  It's better to go with a provider, like IndexTank.

IndexTank also powers Reddit and Wordpress.com, so can bet it'll be reliable.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm using IndexTank and they rock!

Comment: At this moment (2011-12-21), I can't find the sign up page for IndexTank, the one likend from the tutorial gives me an exception, and if I go to the login page, I get an SSL error due to an expired certificate.

Answer (score 4):

SOLR works very nicely -- it's a bit pricey to get starts ($20 a month), but it just works, and works well.

They recently added the ability to ask the user "Did you mean to search for [correct spelling]".

You can easily cross-model search (search for Users and Cars and Dealerships).

Comment: Eh, that problem with them is I simply can't get it running..neither on my app's Heroku account nor localhost.

Comment: Emil, the install instructions at http://docs.heroku.com/websolr should cover getting up and running with your own local Solr instance. Should just be `heroku rake sunspot:solr:start` -- I'd welcome feedback on those docs if you have further questions.

Comment: Do you have any link to the documentation on the "Did you mean..." with Solr?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku offers addons which you can easily add to your application. You should take a look at [Solr](http://addons.heroku.com/websolr) and [IndexTank](http://addons.heroku.com/indextank).

Answer (score 3):

There's a free solution in the [Texticle gem](http://texticle.github.io/texticle/). It uses PostgreSQL's (> 8.3) full text index support and creates a search method on your models. If you create indexes, the speed is very good (for a free solution).

Hope that helps!